# Why do I get dependency warnings/errors while removing nginx from Ubuntu?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-10.04, apt, package-management

```
root@ubuntus:~# apt-get remove nginx-light
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nginx-light is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  nginx-full: Depends: nginx-common (= 1.0.5-1ppa2~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How to solve it?

Updated:

```
root@tftc:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nginx-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/60.6kB of archives.
After this operation, 246kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 62634 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nginx-common (from .../nginx-common_1.0.5-1ppa2~lucid_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.0.5-1ppa2~lucid_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx', which is also in package nginx 0:1.0.5-1ppa2~lucid
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for ufw ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.0.5-1ppa2~lucid_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Read line 5. It is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

You broke your system by messing up your package repository. So you have to solve it by issuing in order:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install nginx-common
apt-get remove nginx-full
```

at each step read the messages carefully and follow the given instructions.

**Edit:**
It is still true what I said. You really messed your setup. It's never a good idea to force installs. You tried to install a package not appropriate for your system and then forced another install of the same with another version number. And I don't know which other packages you forced to install/update/remove. (`2 not fully installed or removed.` is a bad thing.) So I would try

```
apt-get remove nginx-common nginx-full
apt-get purge nginx-common nginx-full
apt-get -f install
```

And next time think twice before installing packages meant for other Ubuntu/Debian versions.

Comment: Please, read the updated entry of post. There is something with installing nginx-common...

Answer (score 1):

I just "reproduced" the problem:

- install nginx 0.7.x which is standard in Ubuntu 10.04
- add nginx's PPA
- run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`
- the upgrade fails, trying to remove/purge nginx fails too

The fix:

- remove the nginx PPA (I commented out the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/...`)
- `apt-get purge nginx nginx-full nginx-common` - this now succeeds
- add the PPA again (uncomment the line)
- `apt-get update`, `apt-get install nginx`